# Cannot get to SQL generated in EF Core

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a really annoying issue where I cant get to the SQL that EF Core is generating

I have tried Azure Data Studio, this profiles some of the commands being run, but not those from my application

Loads of sites say to user query.ToQueryString() but this doesnt exist

My variable is of type IQueryable

How can I do this please?

Im using EF Core 3.1

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2):

`ToQueryString()` has been added in EF Core 5.0.

In 3.1, you can turn on the [EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/extensions-logging?tabs=v3) and see the executed SQL commands.

Or you can use the following custom extension method (and remove it when you switch to EF Core 5.0 or later):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    using Query;
    using Query.Internal;

    public static partial class EfCoreExtensions
    {
        public static string ToQueryString<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query)
        {
            var enumerable = query.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(query.Expression);
            var enumerableType = enumerable.GetType();
            var relationalQueryContextField = enumerableType.GetField("_relationalQueryContext", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var relationalQueryContext = (RelationalQueryContext)relationalQueryContextField.GetValue(enumerable);
            var relationalCommandCacheField = enumerableType.GetField("_relationalCommandCache", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var relationalCommandCache = (RelationalCommandCache)relationalCommandCacheField.GetValue(enumerable);
            var relationalCommand = relationalCommandCache.GetRelationalCommand(relationalQueryContext.ParameterValues);
            return relationalCommand.CommandText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly.  One slight tweak in the requirement, is there a way that in a debug scenario, I could get this to be run for all queries against my database?

Comment: This is for debugging only. For the mentioned scenario, use the first option (EF Core logging) - just follow the instructions from the link. It can be configured to output log to the console, debug window and many others.